# Java: how to priority queue HashSet in order of SIZE (smallest first)?

Tags: java, priority-queue, hashset, min-heap

I am trying to implement a priority queue that will order HashSets in order of their size (i.e. smallest HashSets will have the highest priority).

How may I implement this in Java?

Below is my attempt that successfully orders HashSets by their priority number (highest first).

My main method:

```
        System.out.print("Enter size of priority queue: ");
        int inputSize = scanner.nextInt();

        HashSetQueue pq = new HashSetQueue(inputSize);

        System.out.println("1. insert");
        System.out.println("2. remove");
        System.out.println("3. check empty");
        System.out.println("4. check full");
        System.out.println("5. empty");
        System.out.println("6. check size");
        System.out.println("7. print");
        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");

        int choice = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
          System.out.print("Please enter a value: ");
          int userInput = scanner.nextInt();

          HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
          set.add(userInput);

          System.out.println("Please enter a priority: ");
          int priority = scanner.nextInt();

          pq.insert(priority, set);
          break;
        case 2:
          System.out.println("\nJob removed \n\n" + pq.remove());
          break;
        case 3:
          System.out.println("\nEmpty Status: " + pq.isEmpty());
          break;
        case 4:
          System.out.println("\nFull Status: " + pq.isFull());
          break;
        case 5:
          System.out.println("\nPriority Queue Cleared!");
          pq.clear();
          break;
        case 6:
          System.out.println("\nSize = " + pq.size());
          break;
        case 7:
          pq.print();
          break;
        default:
          System.out.println("\nPlease enter a valid number on the list!");
          break;
```

My PriorityQueue class

```
import java.util.HashSet;

/** class Task **/
class Task {
  int priority;
  HashSet<Integer> job;

  /** Constructor **/
  public Task(int priority, HashSet<Integer> job) {
    this.job = job;
    this.priority = priority;
  }

  /** toString() **/
  public String toString() {
    return "\nPriority : " + priority + "\nJob Name : " + job;
  }
}

/** Class PriorityQueue **/
class HashSetQueue {
  private Task[] heap;
  private int heapSize, capacity;

  /** Constructor **/
  public HashSetQueue(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity++;
    heap = new Task[this.capacity];
    heapSize = 0;
  }

  /** function to clear **/
  public void clear() {
    heap = new Task[capacity];
    heapSize = 0;
  }

  /** function to check if empty **/
  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return heapSize == 0;
  }

  /** function to check if full **/
  public boolean isFull() {
    return heapSize == capacity - 1;
  }

  /** function to get Size **/
  public int size() {
    return heapSize;
  }

  public void print() {
    Task item;

    for (int i = 1; i <= heapSize; i++) {
      item = heap[i];
      System.out.println(item);
    }
  }

  /** function to insert task **/
  public void insert(int priority, HashSet<Integer> job) {
    Task newJob = new Task(priority, job);

    heap[++heapSize] = newJob;
    int pos = heapSize;
    while (pos != 1 && newJob.priority > heap[pos / 2].priority) {
      heap[pos] = heap[pos / 2];
      pos /= 2;
    }
    heap[pos] = newJob;
  }

  /** function to remove task **/
  public Task remove() {
    int parent, child;
    Task item, temp;
    if (isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("Heap is empty");
      return null;
    }

    item = heap[1];
    temp = heap[heapSize--];

    parent = 1;
    child = 2;
    while (child <= heapSize) {
      if (child < heapSize && heap[child].priority < heap[child + 1].priority)
        child++;
      if (temp.priority >= heap[child].priority)
        break;

      heap[parent] = heap[child];
      parent = child;
      child *= 2;
    }
    heap[parent] = temp;

    return item;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch how many I implement a priority queue that orders the HashSet by size? I'm not familiar with the comparator function for PriorityQueue!

Comment: Use PriorityQueue with your own comparator  : PriorityQueue(Comparator<? super E> comparator)  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change this line:

```
while (pos != 1 && newJob.priority > heap[pos / 2].priority) {
```

to:

```
while (pos != 1 && newJob.job.size() < heap[pos / 2].job.size()) {
```

this will insert the new task before another tasks with more jobs.

On the other hand if it's not for education purpose, then don't try to reinvent the wheel and just use a `PriorityQueue` with your `Comparator`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this:

```
PriorityQueue<HashSet> priorityQueueOfHashSets = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(set -> set.size()));
```